# end-of-line widget not working in functions (zsh-autosuggestions)

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Why will this

```bash
bindkey '^ ' end-of-line
```

works, and accept the suggestion, but

```bash
function accept {
  zle end-of-line
}
zle -N accept
bindkey '^ ' accept
```

this won't work.

I don't understand why. I also tried to replace `end-of-line` with `autosuggest-accept` in the function, but still nothing happens...

---

What I try to do is having two keybinding:

- **ctrl+space**: accept the suggestion and execute the line
  easily done by `bindkey '^ ' autosuggest-accept`
- **ctrl+alt+space**: accept the suggestion, add `sudo` at the beginning and execute.
  I tried this:

```
function insert-sudo-accept {
  zle end-of-line
  LBUFFER="sudo $LBUFFER"
  zle accept-line
}
```

But again as I said `zle end-of-line` does not work, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When a keybinding’s widget is activated, the Zsh Line Editor (ZLE) sets the `$WIDGET` parameter to the name of the activated widget.
- In turn, `zsh-autosuggestions` checks whether the value of `$WIDGET` is a member of `$ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS`. If so, it will accept the suggestion.
- However, inside your widget function, when you call `zle end-of-line`, this will *not* change the value of `$WIDGET`.

There are three ways to solve this:

- Bind `zsh-autosuggestion`’s own `autosuggest-accept` widget to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>:

  ```bash
  bindkey '^@' autosuggest-accept
  ```
- Call `zle end-of-line -w`. This will update `$WIDGET` to the name of the widget you’re calling.
- Add your widget to `$ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS`:

  ```bash
  ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS+=(
      <insert widget name here>
  )
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, all that I needed was to register my widget name, `ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS+=(insert-sudo-accept)` Your answer helped me to find that out!